# PHP substring extraction. Get the string before the first '/' or the whole string

Tags: php, string, substring

I am trying to extract a substring. I need some help with doing it in PHP.

Here are some sample strings I am working with and the results I need:

```
home/cat1/subcat2 => home

test/cat2 => test

startpage => startpage
```

I want to get the string till the first `/`, but if no `/` is present, get the whole string.

I tried,

```
substr($mystring, 0, strpos($mystring, '/'))
```

I think it says - get the position of `/` and then get the substring from position 0 to *that* position.

I don't know how to handle the case where there is no `/`, without making the statement too big.

Is there a way to handle that case also without making the PHP statement too complex?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->beforeFirst('/')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L389) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

```
$arr = explode("/", $string, 2);
$first = $arr[0];
```

In this case, I'm using the `limit` parameter to `explode` so that php won't scan the string any more than what's needed.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. It worked :) But one question. I am only able to do this -> `$arr = explode('/',$mystring,2); echo $arr[0];`. I am unable to get the first string in one statement itself - `echo explode('/',$mystring,2)[0];`. Since explode returns an array, I should be able to do it right? But I get an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Php doesn't like you indexing into return values from functions.

Comment: oh. okay. would have been nice if it was possible.

Comment: `list($first,) = explode("/", $string, 2);`

Comment: `explode() + [0]` is a long-winded way to write `strtok($string, "/")`

Comment: Isn't it overkill to create a whole new array? That's what `explode` does.

Comment: by the way, you can do explode("/", $string, 2)[0] in php 5.5

Comment: @mario The problem with `strtok()` is `first/second` will return `first` but `/second` will return `second` rather than an empty string.

Answer (score 413):

The **most efficient** solution is the [`strtok`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function:

```
strtok($mystring, '/')
```

NOTE: In case of more than one character to split with the results may not meet your expectations e.g. `strtok("somethingtosplit", "to")` returns `s` because it is splitting by any single character from the second argument (in this case `o` is used).

@friek108 thanks for pointing that out in your comment.

For example:

```
$mystring = 'home/cat1/subcat2/';
$first = strtok($mystring, '/');
echo $first; // home
```

and

```
$mystring = 'home';
$first = strtok($mystring, '/');
echo $first; // home
```

Comment: This is also about 40% faster than the `current-explode` solution. (Not that I use it so often that it matters.)

Comment: This should be the excepted answer. Definitely faster and more memory and CPU cycles efficient then any of the `explode` solutions given.

Comment: The problem with `strtok` is `first/second` will return `first` but `/second` will return `second` rather than an empty string.

Comment: Further to my above comment: *The behavior when an empty part was found changed with PHP 4.1.0. The old behavior returned an empty string, while the new, correct, behavior simply skips the part of the string*

Comment: Brilliant. Much cleaner than using explode and then having to index into the array. Preferred solution.

Comment: This is not that safe in some circumstances - for example try this: `echo strtok("history_table_id","_id"); `. It returns simply "h". Be careful!

Comment: This however handles differently depending on if the string by which is split, is longer than 1 character.

Answer (score 102):

```php
$first = explode("/", $string)[0];
```

Comment: elegant, but not very efficient in computer time.  But these days folks don't care much anymore about the minute CPU cycles

Answer (score 21):

What about this :

```
substr($mystring.'/', 0, strpos($mystring, '/'))
```

Simply add a '/' to the end of mystring so you can be sure there is at least one ;)

Comment: You can just check if there is one slash in the string before doing this. Anyway, it's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 14):

Late is better than never. php has a predefined function for that. here is that good way.

```
strstr
```

if you want to get the part before match just set **before_needle** (3rd parameter) to `true`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
function not_strtok($string, $delimiter)
{    
    $buffer = strstr($string, $delimiter, true);

    if (false === $buffer) {
        return $string;
    }

    return $buffer;
}

var_dump(
    not_strtok('st/art/page', '/')
);
```

Comment: This is not safe to use if you can't be sure that the needle exists in the string.

Comment: @fooquency — True, but you can always add the character to the end of the string you are checking, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. My tests showed that `strstr` is slightly faster than `strtok`. I will go with the former.

Answer (score 13):

One-line version of the accepted answer:

```
$out=explode("/", $mystring, 2)[0];
```

Should work in php 5.4+

Comment: Unlike the one below, the "2" limits the number of array items it creates. Good thinking.

Comment: Is there a reason that we needed a new answer to show this condensed version of the accepted answer? Couldn't this be a comment under the accepted answer or an edit of the accepted answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes

Comment: "Yes" to what? You agree that a comment or edit would have done the same job?

Comment: @mickmackusa No

Answer (score 9):

This is probably the shortest example that came to my mind:

```
list($first) = explode("/", $mystring);
```

1) `list()` will automatically assign string until `"/"` if delimiter is found 
2) if delimiter `"/"`is not found then the whole string will be assigned

...and if you get really obsessed with performance, you may add extra parameter to explode `explode("/", $mystring, 2)` which limits maximum of the returned elements.

Comment: I like this approach. Saves making an unnecessary array. And `strtok()` is unsafe.

Comment: @rybo111: What is unsafe about `strtok()`?

Comment: @rybo111 I echo hakre's sentiment; what makes `strtok()` unsafe?

Comment: @hakre See my replies to jmarceli's answer. It can cause unexpected behaviour depending on the PHP version.

Comment: php 4.1.0 - rly?

Comment: @hakre If you're > 4.1.0 (and I hope you are) then the behaviour might not be what you expect, because it'll skip empty tokens.

Comment: A token can not be empty, and [that behavior is documented](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html). The token always starts at the first byte *not* a delimiter. That is, there is never an empty token. This is useful, especially for path separators when you always want the first segment or a further on segment. `///first//////second/third/`

Comment: @hakre The title of this question says "Get the string before the first '/'" - `strtok` will not strictly do that (as in your example), which is my point.

Comment: The OP gives example which state that the first token has a non-zero length and strtok does exactly that for the OPs case - so if you talk about strictness, there is no unexpected behaviour of strtok here even if you skip the docs.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using a regex like this:

```
$s = preg_replace('|/.*$|', '', $s);
```

sometimes, regex are slower though, so if performance is an issue, make sure to benchmark this properly and use an other alternative with substrings if it's more suitable for you.

Comment: Regex is probably overkill too, but since I say the same about `explode` it would be interesting to see which is faster.

Comment: there's absolutely nothing wrong with this and I can't think of why it would deserve 2 downvotes.  I personally wouldn't use regex but it's certainly not wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The function strstr() in PHP 5.3 should do this job.. The third parameter however should be set to true..

But if you're not using 5.3, then the function below should work accurately:

```
function strbstr( $str, $char, $start=0 ){
    if ( isset($str[ $start ]) && $str[$start]!=$char ){
        return $str[$start].strbstr( $str, $char, $start+1 );
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it though, but this should work just fine.. And it's pretty fast as well

Comment: +1 for `strstr()`, but be aware that it returns `false` if the string doesn't contain `$needle`, thus the `explode()` solutions above are a better fit in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Using `current` on `explode` would ease the process.

```
 $str = current(explode("/", $str, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a helper function to take care of that:

```
/**
 * Return string before needle if it exists.
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param mixed $needle
 * @return string
 */
function str_before($str, $needle)
{
    $pos = strpos($str, $needle);

    return ($pos !== false) ? substr($str, 0, $pos) : $str;
}
```

Here's a use case:

```
$sing = 'My name is Luka. I live on the second floor.';

echo str_before($sing, '.'); // My name is Luka
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode("/", $string, 2); $first = $arr[0];
```

This Way is better and more accurate than `strtok`
because if you wanna get the values before @ for example
while the there's no string before @ it will give you whats after the sign .
but `explode` doesnt

Answer (score -1):

```
$string="kalion/home/public_html";

$newstring=( stristr($string,"/")==FALSE ) ? $string : substr($string,0,stripos($string,"/"));
```

Comment: There is absolutely zero benefit in calling a case-insensitive function when the needle is a non-letter.  This code-only answer only distracts from better answers on this page, so I am voting to delete.

Answer (score -1):

why not use:

```
function getwhatiwant($s)
{
    $delimiter='/';
    $x=strstr($s,$delimiter,true);
    return ($x?$x:$s);
}
```

OR:

```
   function getwhatiwant($s)
   {
       $delimiter='/';
       $t=explode($delimiter, $s);
       return ($t[1]?$t[0]:$s);
   }
```

Comment: I see that there is no comment with the dv on this post, so let me explain.  If the input string is `0/` then you will get an incorrect result because the ternary is just doing a _falsey_ check.  As for your your second snippet, this suffers from something that gnud's answer avoids (4 years earlier) -- the fact that you do not limit the explosions means that potentially more than 2 elements will be created, but you only need the first one.  This code-only answer can safely be removed.

Comment: Actually the ternary here is very nice and concise.  This is a very useful method for strings that are known not to be "0$delimiter".  Such as a date from which it is desired to remove sub seconds portion.  The OP doesn't specify any string criteria.  I found this to be very useful for what I needed.  Glad it wasn't removed.  I would one line it though.  `$substr = strstr($string, $delimiter, true) ?: $string;`