# Whats The use of function strtok() in PHP, how is better than other string function doing the same thing?

Tags: php, string, strtok

Whats the use of function `strtok()` in PHP? How is better than other string function doing the same thing?

Comment: You can see also that https://stackoverflow.com/a/24280162/4217744

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is no other string function that does the *same* thing. Functions like `explode` return the complete split string in an array. `strtok` on the other hand only returns one piece at a time, with each subsequent call returning the next piece. This is potentially much more economic and memory preserving for large strings.

Answer (score 7):

`strtok` is preferred over other function when you have to **split a string on more than one delimiter**.

The other function that this like [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), [split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) are regex based and will have associated overhead with them.

Answer (score 6):

```
$addr=strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?');
```

but do not call it "better". it's just another way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

`strtok()` is a great and very useful function but:

- > This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE` ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php#refsect1-function.strtok-notes)).
- > If you want to tokenize by only one letter, `explode(`) is much faster compared to `strtok()` ([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php#115124)).
- > If you have memory-usage critical solution, you should keep in mind, that strtok function holds input string parameter (or reference to it?) in memory after usage ([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php#103051)).