# How to cut string after comma

Tags: php, substring

```
$A=123132,32132,123132321321,3
$B=1,32,99
$C=456,98,89
$D=1
```

I want to cut string after first comma

output. . .

```
$A=123132
$B=1
$C=456
$D=1
```

Comment: php.net provides a nice reference documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$newA = current(explode(",", $A));`

from: [PHP substring extraction. Get the string before the first '/' or the whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935918/php-substring-extraction-get-the-string-before-the-first-or-the-whole-strin)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) to get the position of the first comma, and [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the value prior to it:

```
<?php

    $val='123132,32132,123132321321,3';
    $a=substr($val,0,strpos($val,','));

    echo $a;

?>
```

Output:

> 123132

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this:

```
substr($A,0,strpos($A,","))
```

or

current(explode(",", $A))

will both return the value `123132`

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
$A='123132,32132,123132321321,3';
$t=explode(',',$A);
$result = $t[0];
```