# get width from css comments php

Tags: php, html, string

I have a php string like bellow,

```
$str= ' <html>------- <style type="text/css">@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { .message_mobile,.mesage_logo_mobile { width: 100% !important;} } .message_mobile{ width:600px;} /*message_width 600px */</style> -----</html>';
```

I need to read `600px` from `/*message_width 600px */` Is it possible to get that value from the string?

Comment: This might help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935918/php-substring-extraction-get-the-string-before-the-first-or-the-whole-strin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\.message_mobile\s*\{\s*width:\s*(\d+)/s', $str, $tmp)) {
    $width = $tmp[1];
} else {
    $width = "not defined";
}
```

that if html was generated not by you. What's the reason do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
$pos = strpos($str, '600px');

if ($pos === true) {
    [your code here];
}
```

Is this what you're looking for? strpos() function.

Comment: he want to get value fro css property, not check if substring exists